# ArUco markers, why does the pose change when I change image resolution?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration, aruco, pose

I use this reference https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-perform-pose-estimation-using-an-aruco-marker/  to estimate pose of a marker.

When I obtain cam matrix and distortion matrix I used the full camera resolution.

However, when I change the resolution (image size) before pose estimation, I am getting different results. I am not sure why and which resolution would be correct to use.

Should we always use the same resolution as what was used for camera calibration?

I expected the pose to be somewhat independent from image size other than minor changes. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, **always** use the **same** resolution.

One *could* recalculate the camera matrix and distortion coefficients to fit a *different* resolution but that's a hassle, and requires some knowledge of *how* the camera made these pictures (binning, cropping). Unless you understand the math behind it, just stick with same resolution.

Comment: Thanks Christoph! for the edits, and answer.

Comment: I posted another question, please take a look if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70956515/aruco-markers-pose-estimatimation-exactly-for-which-point-the-traslation-and-r